# What permissions are required for SetTokenInformation to work?

Tags: windows, permissions, token, privileges, requirements

I'm trying to set the UIAccess flag in a token to true using `SetTokenInformation`, but I keep getting the same error – 1314: A required privilege is not held by the client.  What permissions are required for `SetTokenInformation` to work properly?

Comment: SeTcbPrivilege is the most likely candidate; if that doesn't work, you may have to resort to trial and error.  Enable them all, and see if that works!  Also, it might only work with a new token, i.e., one that hasn't been used yet.  If so, you can create a new token from an existing one with DuplicateTokenEx.

Comment: The process is admin level, and the token I'm trying to alter is a duplicate token from `DuplicateTokenEx`. I've tried doing the same thing to my own process's token, but all I get is error 5 – Access is denied. Would you have any knowledge regarding that?

Comment: For permissions, would MAXIMUM_ALLOWED do the trick?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the reason you get access denied for your own token is that it is in use.  As for the duplicated token, admin level probably isn't enough; it doesn't have SeTcbPrivilege, for a start.  Typically you have to be running as local system to do this sort of stuff.  I'm not sure about the access mask, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED may work, or try TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS|GENERIC_ALL.  You might need to check the ACL, or turning debug privilege on might bypass permissions checking.  I find little information online on what UIAccess is or how to use it, so I'm just guessing here.